# MGET calls getting slower and slower under load using Stackexchange.Redis

Tags: performance, redis, asp.net-core, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I have a ASP.Net Core Web API running in a linux container in AWS ECS.  This API gets data out of Redis mostly, but will fallback to a database if it is not there (we have engineered where 99.99% of our data is in the Redis cache).  I have a reasonably high load coming in at about 1-2K RPS (sure maybe medium to small to some of you ;-).

This API looks up several keys via MGET (anywhere from 20-60) for each request.  Everything is async all the way, no sync code or Waits or other deadlock prone code.  Things just get slower and slower the more the RPS goes up.  I also tried PreserveAsyncOrder = false, but that seemed to be worse.

I do not think my Redis server (which is in Elasticache) is the issue, metrics show barely 1% CPU utilization.  Also the more instances of my container I create, the more latency goes down, something I wouldn't expect to see if the server is the bottleneck.

I heard there was a potential thread hijacking issue with TPL and SE.Redis (not sure if it is fixed or not, or applicable to .Net Core), so I tried moving everything to sync instead of async (although my web api calls are still async, but my calls to SE.Redis are sync).  This resulted in actual timeouts rather then just taking awhile:

Timeout performing MGET, inst: 5, queue: 199, qu: 0, qs: 199, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 150304, ar: 0, clientName: , serverEndpoint: 10.55.148.227:6379, keyHashSlot: -2

Being as this is .Net Core the timeout exception seems to give less info than full stack, I do not see the number of worker threads or IOCP threads to see if there is a bottleneck there.

As more and more timeouts occur, the queue/qs: number goes up as well as the in: number.

The in number leads me to believe I am getting a response just not processing it fast enough, could I be falling prey to the thread hijacking issue?  Or maybe my client is network bound?

I also have tried creating a connection pool for redis connections, as indicated on the SE.Redis timeouts page.  Very small improvement, but still facing the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Redis is single-threaded. You're increasing load on the single thread so it makes sense that it gets slower to respond. MGET is just multiple GET operations in a single batch, so if you're doing 20-60 GETs for each request and 2k requests per second, then Redis is doing about 30-120k ops/second.

Either you're hitting the max throughput for your cloud VM cpu or network saturation.

Try doing some load testing with random keys to find the max capacity first so you know if that's enough for your application, then you can model around it.

You can use hashes to combine similar data into a single key or use sharding with more servers (or instances on more CPUs). Redis cluster does automatic sharding.

Comment: I am sure this is not the issue.  1.  In the original issue above I mentioned that the Redis server seems to be barely breaking a sweat.  And in fact if I connect from a different machine everything is still fast.  2.  You can see that there is a local queue that is unprocessed.  That is not related to the server.  3.  I have written my own library since this doesn't seem to be addressed and that does not suffer from this issue.